# Save Data to Shapefile with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, kml, openlayers, shapefile

I am creating a web application using OpenLayers. I have implemented functionality such that a user can add a point or polygon to the map that is displayed using JavaScript. I now need to save this data to a shapefile. Any ideas on how?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old thread but I came here with the same question after doing a bit of googling myself to see if there was anything out there. I concluded that there wasn't but that there could be, so I wrote it:

https://code.google.com/p/js2shapefile/

It's the first time I've done anything along these lines in Javascript so I'm sure you'll find all kinds of oddities with my code...but, it works, for ESRI Javascript API graphics and Google Maps markers, at any rate. It could be easily extended to take OpenLayers vectors as input too, but I haven't got round to doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to do it on the server, unless there's a javascript implementation of shapelib.

Actually, do you want the web user to get a shapefile to save or do you want to save it on the server?

There's lots of ways of doing it on a server, depending on your server language of choice. In python, you just import the ogr library and write it... You'll need to construct a web request from the client with the data in it though...

Maybe geoscript can help:

http://geoscriptblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/merging-shapefiles-with-javascript.html

Comment: I've just been trying to use JavaScript and the OpenLayers API. I think I might be able to use the commit function but I'm not sure how exactly. Not familiar at all with Python so can't use that option. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe I need to convert to a KML file?

Comment: Again, where is this shapefile going? Saved on the web server, or back to the user at the web client? What are your [web] skills?

Comment: I think it should be on the server. My web skills aren't that great.

Comment: You better get some! You'll need some authentication so random users cant dump stuff on your server (unless you want them to). And you'll need a way of crafting a web request (via a form POST ideally) to send the data to the server, which can then create the file in some place. Its not looking easy...

Comment: Haha. You're so encouraging! But don't worry. Working on a small JavaScript function that's gonna do the job for me...

Answer (score 0):

There's a good overview on this issue [here](http://techslides.com/online-shapefile-to-geojson-converter/). For converting to shape using client side javascipt only, you could base you work on the [JavaScript Shapefile to GeoJSON library](https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson).